# Is it possible to have conditional dependencies in gulp?

Tags: gulp

I have two requirements for my build script:

1. When I run `gulp clean build`, `clean` must complete before `build`
   starts.
2. If I run `gulp build`, then `clean` shouldn't run.

So, if `clean` is specified, then `build` should wait for it, else start.

The first part is possible if I do

```
gulp.task('clean');
gulp.task('build', ['clean']);
```

However, that violates point 2

If I do

```
gulp.task('clean');
gulp.task('build');
```

That violates point 1

Is this possible with gulp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot run two gulp tasks with the same command like you did with dependency management you want.

Anyway you can pass an argument to your `build` task that will allow, using a little ternary, to wait for the `clean` one to complete before running.

So something like this:

```
gulp.task('build', (process.argv[3] === '--clean') ? ['clean'] : null, function () {
  ...
});
```

This way, you can launch your build normally with

```
gulp build
```

And when you want to call it with the `clean`:

```
gulp build --clean
```

There is a lot of ways to get better argument handling, like [yargs](https://github.com/chevex/yargs) or the env of [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util). But I found my method nice in the fact that it doesn't need any extra dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use [`Gulp-If`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if)

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
  gulp.src('*.*')
    .pipe(gulpif(condition, clean()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```